# How to map a comID to latitude/longitude?

Tags: hydrology, rivers

I'm working with a dataset of river flow from NOAA and the locations of the measurements are indicated with a comID.

From what I gathered these comIDs are rooted from a dataset called NHD, although I have not found any meaningful information or mapping on them.